# How to check the status of BlueTooth adapter (ON/OFF) with Delphi 10.3 (Firemonkey) App for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am writing an IOT based (BLE) Firemonkey app and I need to check that Bluetooth adapter is Enabled or not for both iOS and Android.

I've found a source [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fbrsatalay.blogspot.com%2F2014%2F10%2Fdelphi-android-broadcast-receiver-ile_22.html%3FshowComment%3D1568578068828%23c171679956588944766) but it is only for android (like many others), but I need a cross platform solution.

Comment: Look at the properties of [`System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothLEManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothLEManager), such as [`ConnectionState`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothLEManager.ConnectionState) and [`CurrentAdapter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Bluetooth.TBluetoothLEManager.CurrentAdapter).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you so much to direct me to the right solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a proper solution on [here](https://igapyon.github.io/diary/2016/ig160311.html).

```
uses System.Bluetooth;

function IsBluetoothLEAdapterEnabled: Boolean;
var
  manager: TBluetoothLEManager;
  adapt: TBluetoothLEAdapter;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    manager := TBluetoothLEManager.CreateInstance;
  except
    exit;
  end;

  try
    adapt := manager.CurrentAdapter;
  except
    exit;
  end;

  try
    if adapt.State = TBluetoothAdapterState.On then
    begin
      // BluetoothLE Adapter was found
      Result := True;
      exit;
    end;
  except
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

end execute like below

```
  if IsBluetoothLEAdapterEnabled then
    ShowMessage('BluetoothLE ON')
  else
    ShowMessage('BluetoothLE OFF');
```